# Any way to copy a syntax-coloured file in Vim as HTML?

Tags: vim

I've got a couple of files loaded in Vim, but I wanted to post the contents with the colouring that Vim is providing.  Short of print-screen, is there a way to do this?  Ideal would be a copy/paste as HTML, but I suspect I'm going to be disappointed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to enter the command

```
:TOhtml
```

Answer (score 5):

Alongside with built-in `:TOhtml` which was already mentioned, you can try my plugin which is more customizable: [format.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3113). Its advantages over 2html are explained on the plugin page.

Answer (score 3):

I put together a solution that I'm pretty happy with recently for copying rich text to paste into my mail client.  Replace the app specifics as appropriate for your setup.

```
" open the selection in Internet Explorer so it can be copied as rich text
function! OpenInIE() range
    execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . 'TOhtml'
    silent !start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %:p
    sleep 2
    silent !del %:p
    q!
endfunction
```

and

```
noremap <F7> :call OpenInIE()<CR>
```

Once the IE window opens, I hit Ctrl-A followed by Ctrl-C and then I have the rich text in the clipboard.

Comment: You need an additional save %:p before starting the IE, otherwise, the file to be opened does not really exist